# How to use the `url('outcome/4star/${random}.jpg')` function in C?

Tags: c, string, file, string-interpolation

this is my code now:

```
srand(time(NULL));   
int photo = rand()%((3+1)-1) + 1; 
fp_r = fopen("ascii_art/Animals/${photo}", "r");
```

i would like to do ('outcome/4star/${random}.jpg') but just in the C language. what can I do?

Comment: You may want to say `fopen(sprintf("ascii_art/Animals/%d", photo), "r");`.

Comment: @tshiono That will not work as `sprintf()` returns an int; interpolated string is first argument.

Comment: @AllanWind you're right. I have confused with other language. :)

Comment: The title and text talk about `outcome/4star/${random}.jpg`; the C code tries to use `ascii_art/Animals/${photo}`.  Which do you actually want?  How many photos do you have?  Are they numbered sequentially or are there gaps?  Do you need to add the `.jpg` suffix?  Why would you write `((3 + 1) - 1)` instead of just `3`?  Do you really only have three photos?

Comment: You got two good answers.  Please accept the best one by clicking the check mark next to it so we know you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do:

```
// ...
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    char path[] = "ascii_art/Animals/?.jpg";
    path[strcspn(path, "?")] = '1' + rand() % 3;
    fp_r = fopen(path, "r");
}
```

A more general approach would be to use `sprintf()` as suggested by @tshiono.  The easiest option is to hard-code the maximum number of bytes you need at compile-time.  For that it's best to use one of the integer types from stdint.h type like `uint8_t` as you know it's maximum value is `2^8 - 1 = 255` so you need at most `3` bytes:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TEMPLATE "ascii_art/Animals/%" PRIu8 ".jpg"

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    char path[sizeof(TEMPLATE) - sizeof(PRIu8) + 3];
    sprintf(path, TEMPLATE, (uint8_t) (rand() % 3 + 1));
    fp_r = fopen(path, "r);
}
```

Alternatively, use `log10()` or write a function count number of bytes you need for `photo` at run-time.  `path` is now a variable length array (VLA) or you have to heap allocate it with `malloc()` or friends.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support string interpolation at the language level<sup>1</sup>. You must use functions, and manage your buffers manually.

[`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is useful for performing string interpolation, due to the fact that, on success, it returns the number of characters required to fully render the resultant string, minus the null-terminating byte.

For a fixed buffer, this makes it easy to detect when the string has been cut short. Consider the following (contrived) example, which as a 1 in 10 chance of the resultant string being too long for the buffer.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    char filename[24];

    int n = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    errno = 0;
    int rc = snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "ascii_art/Animals/%d.jpg", n);

    if (rc < 0 || rc >= sizeof filename) {
        if (errno)
            perror("snprintf");
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "String truncation occurred.\n");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Generated path: <%s>\n", filename);

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file) {
        /* ... */
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
Generated path: <ascii_art/Animals/2.jpg>
$ ./a.out
String truncation occurred.
```

The second benefit of this is that passing a *size* of `0` to `snprintf` allows you to determine how large your buffer must be - in the event you want to dynamically allocate it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PATH_TEMPLATE "ascii_art/Animals/%d.jpg"

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    int n = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, PATH_TEMPLATE, n);

    if (-1 == len) {
        perror("snprintf");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *filename = malloc(len + 1);

    if (!filename || -1 == sprintf(filename, PATH_TEMPLATE, n)) {
        perror("failure to dynamically allocate filename");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Generated path: <%s>\n", filename);

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file) {
        /* ... */
        fclose(file);
    }

    free(filename);
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
Generated path: <ascii_art/Animals/3.jpg>
$ ./a.out
Generated path: <ascii_art/Animals/10.jpg>
```

As an alternative, [`asprintf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) is a GNU (and [BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/asprintf)) function that does pretty much exactly the same thing as the previous example: sizes and dynamically allocates a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    char *filename = NULL;
    int n = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    if (-1 == asprintf(&filename, "ascii_art/Animals/%d.jpg", n)) {
        perror("asprintf");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Generated path: <%s>\n", filename);

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file) {
        /* ... */
        fclose(file);
    }

    free(filename);
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
Generated path: <ascii_art/Animals/6.jpg>
$ ./a.out
Generated path: <ascii_art/Animals/4.jpg>
```

---

<sup>1. Excluding [string literal concatenation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases).</sup>

Comment: Good answer.  Any reason why you change % from `3` to `10`?

Comment: @AllanWind Getting an example of `snprintf` truncating the output depending on the inconsistency of the input is impossible with the range [1, 3].